# Where can I publish politically incorrect writing?

Tags: creative-writing

Some writings offend the current political mainstream, because they contradict the prevailing opinions and propose different values. Where can such writing be published?

Samples of writing are http://getrichbangbabes.com/fiona-understand-what-it-truly-means-to-be-human/

One place where we am posting this is in http://www.usmessageboard.com/

All we care is exposure. We don't care about money.

Also the writing is politically incorrect because it makes fun of feminists and most religious people.

Comment: Why do you want to post this sort of material?

Comment: Science fiction. Send it to a press. They print these things. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogg_%28novel%29 See what I mean?

Comment: "Politically incorrect" in what way? Discriminating? Subversive? Unethical? Vulgar? Pornographic?

Comment: "political incorrect" as in "I have no respect for groups I don't belongt to"?

Comment: No. If there are several answers, just list them all. I am not asking for one specific places.

Comment: @user21795 That's not how stackexchange works.

Comment: So people cannot ask what are the colors of rainbow?

Comment: @user21795 Please read the comment by *what* again.

Comment: There are similar very popular questions but for general writing. I forget where.

Answer (score 4):

Why does politically incorrect writing need a special place of publication?

Many works of art criticize the current state of affairs. Political change, subversion, or social analysis are the motivation behind many works of art.

Currently in the West we have a dominant feminist ideology. Writing something not feminist, or anti-feminist, appears politically incorrect. But half a century ago, the dominant ideology was what feminists call "patriarchal", and feminist writing was politically incorrect. So where was it published? **Wherever it would get the most exposure.**

Mainstream publishers avoided feminist writing at first, so feminists created their own publishing houses, their own printed magazines, and as their thoughts gained acceptance, they were slowly picked up by mainstream presses. Today, feminist writing is often no longer discernible as such, because it has become the common thing.

So if you have a political agenda, **the first thing you will want to attempt is getting into mainstream publishing**. You want to be read, and to reach the widest possible audience you will want to get published by a publisher that has the power to get your book into book stores and reviewed by the major news papers and tv shows.

If getting into mainstream publishing does not work, you will need a network of like-minded people and create your own outlet. If you want to change the world, as feminism did, you cannot manage that alone, so **your second step must be to find or create a community of people who want to fight alongside you**. What that community's outlet will be, will depend on the message you want to send and the target audience. It could be a blog, a YouTube channel, a newspaper, a print-publishing house, or anything else – but most likely it will be *all of the above*. You (and your community) will need to be your own marketing managers and think about how you can reach your readers and make your writing sell. Again, think of feminism fifty years ago and how they spread their ideas. There's lots of books that summarize their strategies, and you can learn a lot from them.

Your question, then, shouldn't be where you can publish politically incorrect writing. If it is good writing, and not too offensive, it will get published by regular publishers. If it is too offensive, your question needs to be, where you can find a community of like-minded people that supports each other in publishing their works. If it is bad writing, then you need to learn to write and should stop thinking about publishing anyway.

Comment: the writing makes fun of feminism and religions. who would like that?

Comment: @user21795 Making fun of feminism and religion is something that many people enjoy and it is regularly done in the media. If your writing does not meet with much support then maybe you need to read the last sentence of my answer again.

Comment: and how to reach "the media" knows some websites?

Comment: @user21795 I will gladly repeat myself: If you write a short story, then approach publishers of short stories; if you write a novel, approach publishers of novels; if you write non-fiction, approach publishers of non-fiction. If you do not know how to approach publishers and which publishers to approach, research that. If your writing is well-written but offensive, then create your own outlet. If you do not know how to go about that, learn publishing and marketing and network. If your writing is bad, learn to write.

Comment: any sample publishers I should contact?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar sort of dilemma and my solution was to create a blog on blogger.com. Probably you could try this.

Comment: I think political forum is the way to go http://www.usmessageboard.com/threads/a-nation-founded-by-geniuses-but-run-by-idiots.536383/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aqlli.com](http://www.aqlli.com/#/aq-book) to post your writing.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. We discourage link-only or link-limited answers because link rot may make them useless to future readers. Can you edit your answer to explain what the site is and why it would be useful to the OP?